# How does linux know what btrfs subvol to mount as root?

Tags: btrfs

I have a btrfs filesystem that looks like this:

```
root_subvol        # subvolid=5 - the root subvolume for the btrfs filesystem
  - snapshots/     # Folder that contains btrfs snapshots of the subvol_root that I take before I do system updates
  - subvol_root/   # A btrfs subvolume. Gets mounted as /. Contains /etc, /home, /proc, ...
```

Right now, `subvol_root` is mounted at boot as my `/`.
How does Linux know that that's the subvolume to mount at boot for `/`?

Sure, my subvol_root/etc/fstab has this entry:

```
UUID=84ee... /  btrfs  subvol=subvol_root,...
```

But a different subvolume could have its own version of `/etc/fstab` that would list a different subvolume to mount as `/`, so that would be ambiguous.

Does it look at `/etc/fstab` of the default btrfs subvolume or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your kernel boot parameters, e.g. with `cat /proc/cmdline`.

You may find there a `root=` option that specifies the filesystem, possibly by label or UUID, and a `rootflags=` option that includes `subvol=subvol_root`. These options would be included in your bootloader configuration, as that's what determines the normal kernel command line.

Alternatively, the boot process could rely on the copy of `/etc/fstab` that has been included into initramfs.

Different distributions may do things differently, but generally it's been my experience that the location of the root filesystem tends to be specified by kernel boot parameters, to allow it to be easily modified at boot time if you are e.g. making major changes to your hardware configuration.

If the root filesystem was only specified within initramfs, you might find yourself in a Catch-22-like situation: "I cannot access the root filesystem until I modify my initramfs, but I can't get at the tools I need for modifying my initramfs until I gain access to the root filesystem!"

Comment: Does the entry for `/` in `/etc/fstab` even do anything? It seems like by the time `/etc/fstab` is being read, the root filesystem should already be mounted

Comment: Mostly, it is a placeholder to make life simpler for tools like `udisksd`, so that they can process any filesystems they find without treating the root filesystem as a special case.